# Yii2 using single controller for multiple similar models

Tags: php, yii2

I have few dictionary tables in my scheme. Each one have an ActiveRecord model in app. I need to have simple operations with them (CRUD). So, in common way I have to create separate controller for each model where each action is implemented. I even can use GII for code generation.

But is it possible to use the single controller, say DictionaryController, for manipulating different models? May be model name passed as parameter in constructor.

Comment: yes .. but the problem is how you to define the model by managing...  how do you think passing a value that identifies the model? .. explain better your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simplified example .. you can do in so many different ways the problem is to have a value that lets you choose the model to work on
if you use a param ..  or . post/get values for your call you could

```
public function actionCreate($the_dict)
{
   switch($the_dict) {
      case 'DICT1':
         $model = new Dict1();
         break;
      case 'DICT2' :
         $model = new Dict1();
         break;

     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dict' => $the_dict,
        ]);
    }


  }
```